# Finding the maximum likelihood estimator that can not be isolated (solving a system)

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I have a likelihood function of three parameters $a,b,c$ where distributions of $x_i\mid x_{i-1}$ are normal with mean $x_{i-1}+a(b-x_{i-1})$ and variance $c$. Differentiating and equating the log-likelihood to zero I finally arrive to the following conditions for the MLE of $a,b$ and $c$ based on a sample data $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$,

\begin{align*}
b &= \frac{1}{na}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-x_{i-1}(1-a)\right)\\
a&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})(b-x_{i-1})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b-x_{i-1})^2}\\
c&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1}-a(b-x_{i-1}))^2
\end{align*}

I tried but it seems hopeless to try to isolate one parameter and estimate the others from that one. So I need to use R to, given data $x=(x_0,\dots,x_n)$, find the values for $a,b$ and $c$ but I do not know the command or way of doing this in a smart way, given the sums. Does anybody know how to proceed or eventually a different way to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you state the likelihood function?

Comment: I have that the distributions of $x_i|x_{i-1}$ are normal with mean $x_{i-1}+a(b-x_{i-1})$ and variance $c$. So I compute the likelihood function as $L=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|x_{i-1})$, then the $log(L)$, differentiate, and then equate to 0.